# Replace value in JSON with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I'd like to replace a value in a JSON with **Jolt** but I haven't managed to do so.

My JSON :

```json
{
  "MIRecord": [
    {
      "RowIndex": "0",
      "NameValue": [
        {
          "Name": "MBWHLO",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "MBITNO",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "V_NETA",
          "Value": "123"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowIndex": "1",
      "NameValue": [
        {
          "Name": "MBWHLO",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "MBITNO",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "V_NETA",
          "Value": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to replace :

- `MBWHLO` to `CHANGE1`
- `MBITNO` to `CHANGE2`
- `V_NETA` to `CHANGE3`

My target JSON :

```json
{
  "MIRecord": [
    {
      "RowIndex": "0",
      "NameValue": [
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE1",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE2",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE3",
          "Value": "123"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowIndex": "1",
      "NameValue": [
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE1",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE2",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE13",
          "Value": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I try this but i change all of "Name" value to CHANGE1

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "MIRecord": {
        "*": {
          "NameValue": {
            "*": {
              "Name": "CHANGE1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I don't know if I'm using the right function to replace or if I need to rebuild the whole json. But I'd like to avoid having to redo the json because the input JSON isn't static.

Does anyone have a solution please?

Comment: You are using a wildcard after `"NameValue":`  -->  `"*": {`  ...  I am assuming you will need to list out the individual `Name` properties inside `"NameValue":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`#`** wildcards in order to define new fixed values while conditionally match each one within a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "MIRecord": {
        "*": {
          "NameValue": {
            "*": {
              "Name": {
                "MBWHLO": { "#CHANGE1": "&6[&5].&4[&3].&2" },
                "MBITNO": { "#CHANGE2": "&6[&5].&4[&3].&2" },
                "V_NETA": { "#CHANGE3": "&6[&5].&4[&3].&2" }
              },
              "*": "&4[&3].&2[&1].&"
            }
          },
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Hi @Barbaros you jolt code works perfectly thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To replace the values of `MBWHLO`, `MBITNO`, and `V_NETA` in your JSON with `CHANGE1`, `CHANGE2`, and `CHANGE3`, respectively, you can use the following Jolt transformation:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "MIRecord": {
        "*": {
          "NameValue": {
            "*": {
              "Name": {
                "MBWHLO": "CHANGE1",
                "MBITNO": "CHANGE2",
                "V_NETA": "CHANGE3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This transformation will use the **modify-overwrite-beta** operation to overwrite the values of the Name fields for the `MBWHLO`, `MBITNO`, and `V_NETA` fields with the corresponding values of `CHANGE1`, `CHANGE2`, and `CHANGE3` respectively.

For example, if you apply this transformation to your input JSON, you will get the following output JSON:

```json
{
  "MIRecord": [
    {
      "RowIndex": "0",
      "NameValue": [
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE1",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE2",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE3",
          "Value": "123"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowIndex": "1",
      "NameValue": [
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE1",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE2",
          "Value": "123"
        },
        {
          "Name": "CHANGE3",
          "Value": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use this Jolt transformation to replace the values of `MBWHLO`, `MBITNO`, and `V_NETA` in your JSON without having to rebuild the entire JSON.

Comment: Hi Mohtajj

Unfortunately your JOLT doesn't work. I try it on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Comment: Can You share Code snapshot? or Error you are getting? What is the config you have?

Comment: I share the screenshot as a reply because I couldn't do it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

here's my screenshot, where you can see that the JOLT isn't working as expected

[image]